# How to delete columns without headers in python pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I have to read the CSV file and set the headers in advance. And then drop the columns which I don't want. Is there any way to do this directly?

```
# Current Code
columns_name = ['station', 'date', 'observation', 'value', 'other_1', 
'other_2', 'other_3', 'other_4']
del_columns_name = ['other_1', 'other_2', 'other_3', 'other_4']
df =pd.read_csv('filename', names = columns_name)
df.drop(del_columns_name, axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Possibly you could avoid reading them from the start already. `df.drop(del_columns_name, axis=1, inplace=True)` or `df = df.drop(del_columns_name, axis=1)`

Comment: It's right. But I want to know whether there is a direct way to do my 4 lines codes.

Comment: In that case you might aswell pass the indexes right away.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use your two lists to resolve the indices and column names required.

Then use `usecols` and `names` arguments for [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to specify column indices and names respectively.

```
idx, cols = list(zip(*((i, x) for i, x in enumerate(columns_name) \
                 if x not in del_columns_name)))

df = pd.read_csv('filename', usecols=idx, names=cols, header=None)
```

As explained in the docs, you should also specify `header=None` explicitly when no header exists.

**Explanation**

- Use a generator expression to iterate `columns_name` and remove items not in `del_columns_name`.
- Use `enumerate` to extract indices.
- Use `zip` to create separate tuples for indices and column names.

Comment: I liked the expression but it seems a bit overkill for the small example above but almost necessary if you have a more complex system.

Comment: @AntonvBR, Yeh I'm not really sure where the column names *come from*. It could be from a static config file, for example. In which case, you may be forced into something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might even specify the indexes right away. In this case you are insterested in: `[0,1,2,3]`. Consider this example which also parses dates.

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['station', 'date', 'observation', 'value']

data = '''\
1, 2018-01-01, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2018-01-02, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2'''

file = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=cols, usecols=[0,1,2,3], parse_dates=[1])

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   station       date  observation  value
0        1 2018-01-01            1      1
1        2 2018-01-02            2      2
```